# JS сделать все ссылки в блоке неактивными?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть такой код:

```
<div class='menu'>
   <ul>
       <li><a href="index.php">test 1</a><li>
       <li><a href="index.php">test 1</a><li>
       <li><a href="index.php">test 1</a><li>
       <li><a href="index.php">test 1</a><li>
   <ul>
</div>
```

Как сделать все ссылке в этоv div не активными? 
Или добавить ем всем атрибут disabled.

Comment: нужно выбрать все ссылки внутри этого блока и добавить всем атрибут

Comment: @Grundy, я это понял, я js не знаю как написать

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276133/how-to-disable-html-links

Comment: Пишу вот такое, но не получается $(".menu ul li A ").addClass("result");

Comment: что именно не получается?

Comment: @Grundy, не добавляется класс, это я сделал просто чтоб посмотреть правильно ли я выборку сделал

Comment: кроме неправильной выборки, влияет **когда** вызывается этот код, если при вызове этих элементов еще нет - то и код ничего не добавит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.menu ul li A ', function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
})
```